# document.body.contentEditable not working (bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript

When I press my bookmarklet,

```js
javascript:document.body.contentEditable=true; document.designmode=on; void 0;
```

it doesn't allow me to edit the page anymore, when previously a few weeks back it was working fine. So when I edited the bookmarklet to:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = true; void 0;
```

That doesn't work either. Any ideas why?

EDIT: This works on my other devices but not on my chromebook in which I am experiencing the issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't have errors in the console.

Comment: Does it work on any site?

Comment: ... I tried this on all of the sites

Comment: Notice that it's "on" as a string, not as a variable. So this problem **is caused by a typo**, while it's `javascript: document.body.contentEditable = true; document.designMode = 'on'; void 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my school blocked external javascript execution, as even

```js
alert(`test`)
```

doesn't even work.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your bookmarklet code with this

```
javascript:(() => {document.body.contentEditable=true;})();
```